# How to install a free market application on an android simulator

Tags: android, installation, emulation

I want to install the Photoshop mobile on my emulator. I need to do test the Photoshop.com Mobile integration for image editing. But I dont know how to do that. I cannot access the market from the emulator.
Can anyone tell me how I can install it on my simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally I found a way to do this. Not sure if there are any rules broken while doing this.

Steps to get the free APK and download it is detailed at http://codekiem.com/2012/02/24/apk-downloader/

Once u have the apk with you use the following [ADB](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move) command to install it on the emulator

```
adb install <path_to_apk>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to install the Photoshop mobile
>   on my emulator.

AFAIK, Adobe only makes that application available through the Android Market. If you wish to integrate with it, please use your Android device. You need one of those anyway in order to test your application on hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the apk file from some other source, free to download or ask a friend to get it for you. 
Then you will push that file to the sdcard of the emulator via the DDMS file explorer, and you will install it by launching it.

Comment: Please do not advocate license violations on StackOverflow.

Comment: He is talking about a free market application. But I will correct.

Comment: I was talking about Photoshop mobile which cannot be obtain any means other than android market

Comment: Email them and if you have a good cause they will send it to you.

Answer (score 0):

From Eclipse (supposing it's attached to Android Development Kit), get the application bundle (.apk). Then Import it to Eclipse.

Run it and it will appear in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need the .apk file to run it. Browse the android market from your emulator, locate the app and click and follow the instructions. As pentium said, ask Adobe to send you the apk file and install it on emulator, I do it this way [Install](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-install-apk-files-android-windows-sdk-emulator).